# .NET core middleware does not seem to get a request scoped dependency

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .NET core middleware class that does not seem to get a request scoped version of a dependency. I have a 'repository updater' class that I inject in the InvokeAsync method of a middleware to add data to the respective repository. But when I want to access the same data later on inside the respective repository than the data is away. As if the repository is newly instantiated (see points below the following code)

This is my middleware class:

```cs
    public sealed class ImportMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ImportMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IImxMetadataToRepositoryService imxMetadataToRepositoryService)
        {
            if (!context.Request.HasFormContentType || context.Request.Form.Files.Count == 0)
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            IFormFile imxFile = context.Request.Form.Files.GetFile("imxFile");

            if (imxFile != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = ConvertToBytes(imxFile);
                imxMetadataToRepositoryService.UpdateRepository(bytes, imxFile.FileName);
            }
             
            await _next(context);
        }

        private static byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile file)
        {
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            file.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
    }

    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseImportMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ImportMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

What did I already try:

- When the repository is marked as Singleton instead of Scoped it works. I can access the data stored by the middleware phase. This is highly undesirable for various reasons.
- Using the `HttpContext.RequestServices` is getting the same kind of dependency as the one injected in the InvokeAsync method.

If I miss any needed information, let me know!

Comment: How is your `IImxMetadataToRepositoryService` interface implemented? How to store it? How to access data? I created a simple repository example using your custom middleware, but have no problem using `Scoped`. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I finally found it. I looked over the fact that the logic was running in a seperate 'job'. So the job is out of the same dependency scope. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it. I looked over the fact that the logic was running in a seperate 'job'. So the job is out of the same dependency scope as the request is in.